# SkipTrash in hive in insert overwrite query

Tags: hive, recycle-bin

I have insert overwrite query in hive, After query is executed data is dumped into trash folder.

Is there any option or property by which it can avoided?

Answer (score 1):

In Hive 1.2.0 there is a PURGE option for DROP operation: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9118
and
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7100

**Unfortunately this does not work for external tables and for `insert overwrite` statement.**

But still you can drop files before INSERT OVERWRITE, I know this is not always acceptable solution, using `rm` command with `-skipTrash` option:

```
hadoop fs -rm -r -f -skipTrash  hdfs://your_table_path/*
```

If you are on DEV environment, you may want to disable TRASH feature at all. This can be done by setting `fs.trash.interval=0` in core-site.xml